# Adding Event on native Android Calendar cause NullPointerException

Tags: android, date, calendar

I have tried to use this code (as I have seen in a tutorial)

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();  
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
intent.putExtra("beginTime", dateStart.getTime());
intent.putExtra("allDay", false);
intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=DAILY");
intent.putExtra("endTime", dateEnd.getTime());
intent.putExtra("hasAlarm", 1);
startActivity(intent);
```

to add an event on integrated Calendar in android

But as I wrote get a NullPointerException error on the line

```
startActivity(intent);
```

With this stack

```
07-17 19:12:05.469: W/System.err(30939): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-17 19:12:05.469: W/System.err(30939):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
07-17 19:12:05.469: W/System.err(30939):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
07-17 19:12:05.469: W/System.err(30939):    at myapplication.beachparty.utility.MyUtility.addEventToCalendar(MyUtility.java:44)
07-17 19:12:05.469: W/System.err(30939):    at myapplication.beachparty.it.PartyDetails$2.onClick(PartyDetails.java:114)
07-17 19:12:05.469: W/System.err(30939):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
07-17 19:12:05.479: W/System.err(30939):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
07-17 19:12:05.479: W/System.err(30939):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-17 19:12:05.499: W/System.err(30939):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-17 19:12:05.499: W/System.err(30939):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-17 19:12:05.499: W/System.err(30939):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
07-17 19:12:05.499: W/System.err(30939):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-17 19:12:05.499: W/System.err(30939):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-17 19:12:05.499: W/System.err(30939):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
07-17 19:12:05.499: W/System.err(30939):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
07-17 19:12:05.499: W/System.err(30939):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-17 19:12:07.069: W/System.err(30939): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-17 19:12:07.069: W/System.err(30939):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
07-17 19:12:07.069: W/System.err(30939):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
07-17 19:12:07.069: W/System.err(30939):    at myapplication.beachparty.utility.MyUtility.addEventToCalendar(MyUtility.java:44)
07-17 19:12:07.069: W/System.err(30939):    at myapplication.beachparty.it.PartyDetails$3.onClick(PartyDetails.java:128)
07-17 19:12:07.069: W/System.err(30939):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
07-17 19:12:07.069: W/System.err(30939):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
07-17 19:12:07.069: W/System.err(30939):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-17 19:12:07.069: W/System.err(30939):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-17 19:12:07.069: W/System.err(30939):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-17 19:12:07.069: W/System.err(30939):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
07-17 19:12:07.069: W/System.err(30939):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-17 19:12:07.069: W/System.err(30939):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-17 19:12:07.069: W/System.err(30939):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
07-17 19:12:07.079: W/System.err(30939):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
07-17 19:12:07.079: W/System.err(30939):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)


dateStart
```

ad 
`dateEnd` are 
`Date` objects that indicates the day, mouth, year and time of event

I have tried also to change these lines with

```
intent.putExtra("beginTime", cal.getTimeInMillis());
```

and

```
intent.putExtra("endTime", cal.getTimeInMillis()+60*60*1000);
```

What is wrong?

NB
I have tried the code on Emulator and Samsung Galaxy. And use the API level 10 (GingerBread)

Comment: I'd guess `cal` is null. There should be more to the stack than what you've shown. Also, can you show how `cal` is created?

Comment: I have used simply 'Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();' but I don't know exactly how I must use the cal object

Comment: This shall work as long as `cal` is not, for example, not initialized. Stacktrace is not complete nor we have source line numbers to correlate. Similar code works for me

Comment: the stack is not full. please provide full stack trace. does your app launches the Calendar app or it crashes before?

Comment: Crashes before and doesn't open the calendar... in the stack that I have posted I have omitted only the line that indicates the class with the method invoked by my action listener to add event on calendar that aren't important

Comment: I have added the full stack trace of the error. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot start this activity from another class simply invoking the method,

the line

```
startActivity(intent);
```

cause *NullPointerException* **because haven't a context**

you should pass the `Context` in the method and write

```
mycontext.startActivity(intent);
```

In this way should works.

Answer (score 0):

Check dateStart and dateEnd objects. They might be null. I suggest to put a break-point to the lines where you are adding them to the intent and check if those variables are null or not.

Comment: aren't null and I have tried also to change these lines with   'intent.putExtra("beginTime", cal.getTimeInMillis());'
 and
 'intent.putExtra("endTime", cal.getTimeInMillis()+60*60*1000);'

Comment: If I can see all the code where you are using this code segment, I might be able to help more.

Comment: this code is simply in a method invoked by an action listener in another class I simply do 'MyUtility cm=new MyUtility(); ' 'cm.addEventToccalendar();' and get the error in 'startActivity(intent);' line of cm.addEventToccalendar();

Comment: Can I see the full stack trace, including the nullpointerexception?